# Azure Storage Queue and Managed Identity

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-queues, azure-managed-identity

I am having trouble connecting my Logic App to an Azure Storage Queue. I followed MS guide for setting it up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity

Here is my test Logic App to post something to my queue:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When my Logic App is triggered I get an error:

[image]

AuthenticationFailed.Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Why is it requiring me to include an Authorization Header, when I stated that I want to use Managed Identity? As far as I have read on MS docs, the Queues do support Managed Identities.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: I saw that the in my screenshots here I didn't have the "/messages" in my URL. So it should be https://saqueuespoc.queue.core.windows.net/myqueue01/messages. Without '/messages' in the URL in just gives HTTP 405 Unsupported Verb error. So the main solution for HTTP 403 error with using Managed Identity is to include "x-ms-version" in the request like you stated below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me: [Put/Post JSON message to Azure Storage Queue via Logic App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173016/put-post-json-message-to-azure-storage-queue-via-logic-app/63793717#63793717)

Final result in Logic App designer
[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to my test, if we want to call Azure queue storage rest API with Azure AD auth, we need to specify `x-ms-version` in the request header and its value should be **2017-11-09 or higher**. Otherwise, we will get error 403. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#call-storage-operations-with-oauth-tokens) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services#specifying-service-versions-in-requests)

My test is as below
1. If I do not specify `x-ms-version`, I get the error

[image]

2. If I specify `x-ms-version`, it is ok

My request Headers in HTTP action

```
 "Content-Type": "application/xml",
  "x-ms-date": "@{utcNow('R')}",
  "x-ms-version": "2019-07-07"
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim, thx for the help. It works now. The reason I didn't have x-ms-version to begin with is because I checked out this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message and it states that x-ms-version parameter is optional.
It must be a mistake from MS side, as you were kind to help, that this is actually required. As soon as I provided the x-ms-version parameter it worked and I didn't get the HTTP 403 error.

Comment: @OliverNilsen Since your issue has been resolved, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people.

Comment: I did right after answering on your comment. I also submitted feedback to MS about this paramater and sent a link to this SO post.