# Put/Post JSON message to Azure Storage Queue via Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-queues

I want to be able to use Logic Apps to put/post messages in an Azure Storage Queue, because I want to make use of the Managed Identity option that **HTTP** Logic App acion provides.

I have a Logic App that uses HTTP action to post XML messages to the queue and I have a "Put a message on a queue" action that puts JSON message to the queue for debugging purposes.

My ultimate goal is to be able to use the HTTP action with Managed Identity as Authentication but be able to post JSON messages to the queue like the "Put a message on a queue" action is able to.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you defining the request body in the 1st screenshot (HTTP Post)?

Comment: Yes I will be providing some values. This was just a test value to see that it works with XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Enabled "Managed Identity" on the Logic App.
2. Added Storage-Queue-Contributor permissions on the storage queue.
3. Used `utcnow('R')` to get this date format ("Tue, 08 Sep 2020 12:03:08 GMT")
   for `x-ms-date` HTTP header (no doc from MS about this).
4. Inserted JSON data inside

   ```xml
   <QueueMessage> 
       <MessageText>
       {
         "car": "Audi",
         "year": 1983
       }
      </MessageText>  
   </QueueMessage>
   ```

Final result in Logic App designer:
[image]

Comment: This worked in ADF too!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly send JSON as message body. In fact you can send any text. You just have to ensure that the text you're sending as message body must be XML safe e.g. replace `<` with `&lt;` etc. Generally Base64 encoded string messages are sent to ensure this.

From the [`REST API documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-message#remarks):

> A message must be in a format that can be included in an XML request
>   with UTF-8 encoding. **To include markup in the message, the contents of
>   the message must either be XML-escaped or Base64-encode**. Any XML
>   markup in the message that is not escaped or encoded will be removed
>   before the message is added to the queue.

Comment: I understand the theory you wrote but would you be able to provide an example in the context of my Logic App and specifically how to do it in the HTTP action?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Basically you're consuming Queue Service REST API directly when using HTTP action.

Comment: Are you maybe able to provide and an example of how the Body section would like when I want to post JSON data to a storage queue?

Comment: Btw how do you encode to Base64 for the Body section? How do you do that in the Logic App?